# Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a software application called appTranslator that I have used for many years to manage language translations. It comes with a appTranslatorTESetup (Translator Edition) that i give our translators.

Today I supplied the download link to a user and he was not able to install it. The software was compiled in 2007 so I am assuming it was using the Visual C++ Redistributable 2005.

I looked at the official Microsoft page [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). I can see:

- Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019
- Visual Studio 2013
- Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Studio 2010
- Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Concerning version 2008 it states:

> Visual Studio 2008 reached end of support on April 10, 2018. To aid the discovery of the latest downloads, the links are retained currently, but may be removed in the future.

After another search I came up with:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26347)

Is this considered the latest official available edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26347) I provided is the latest 2005 redist download.

And when my user installed it they were able to run appTranslatorTE.

It may be worth keeping a copy of these redist downloads for legacy app support.

As of 16-04-2022 the link is valid:

[image]

---

I do have some VS2005 Redist downloads on my DropBox folder in some languages:

[image]

Not sure of the est way to make these available for all as an alternative download.

Comment: That link is dead, can this be updated?

Comment: @user2568374 I just clicked it https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26347 and it works. It is not dead. But I have some local downloads.

Comment: sorry, I didn't scroll down far enough

Comment: @user2568374 Great. Please co sides upvoting question / answer if you have found them useful.

Comment: One strange thing I am noticing though is that after I install it it locks me out of windows 10. I did install an old logitech quick cam app after it but not sure which did it. It did this twice. The logon password box doesn't appear and no amount of rebooting fixes it , can't even get to troubleshooting. First time I had to re-install windows, second time I had made an image first and was able to restore. I might post a questio on this.

Comment: @user2568374 Can’t help you there. I have the 2005 runtime installed on Windows 11. All ok.

Comment: Thanks, it might be the Logitech legacy app then, there were only 2 installs each time before it failed and that was the other.